# The "One" Rebus

Tags: rebus

Here is a rebus. Can you solve it?

[image: Rebus]

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE! Congratulations for your first post!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Is it

> The odd one out?

Since that's what it looks like..

Comment: holy darn. Well played.

Answer (score 6):

Is it

> The odd one out?
>  because the one on the left is different than the rest

Comment: Also acceptable.

Comment: our answers are identical